# Is it possible to search the Recycle Bins?

Tags: search, recycle-bin

Is it possible to force a search crawler to crawl through the recycle bin(s) on a SharePoint 2010 system?

I'd like to allow my users to delete files/folders in document libraries but if someone accidentally removes a file that they shouldn't it would make everyone's life a lot easier if items in the recycle bin(s) could be included in normal search results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if there is an OOTB solution for this. I couldn't find one. I was able to find something interesting though. you can search Recycle bin using PowerShell

example : `(Get-SPSite "http://SERVERNAME:PORT/").RecycleBin | ?{$_.Title -match "DeletedFile"}`

[Source](http://markviky.blogspot.com/2010/12/get-files-search-files-from-recycle-bin.html)

Now you can use c# and PowerShell together and write a custom search solution.

Comment: Because I'm very, _very_ new to developing for SharePoint can you point me to any references that would help me build a webpart that my users could interact with to use this functionality?  I've got VS2010 and will soon be able to install the SP Dev Environment on my workstation.

Comment: @JonnyP I will add a link soon. I thought about writing a blog post about it.

Comment: @Shoban - Sweet, I look forward to it!

Comment: This is nice, although it looks like it searches the site collection recycle bin only, and not the bins of each site?

Comment: @Shoban - Any update on that blog post?

Comment: @JonnyP Sorry for the delay. Almost complete. Working on some migration projects and its taking away all the time :( I will update soon.

Comment: @Shoban - Poke, poke.  I'd still love to see this blog post. :)

Comment: @jonnyP ... Apologies for the very late reply. Finally managed to write a blog post and was able to find a better solution in c# too. Check this post : http://allaboutmoss.com/2011/11/04/recycle-bin-search-webpart-for-sharepoint/

Comment: @Shoban - Not at all, thanks for the great write up!

Answer (score 1):

As Shoban stated. Powershell is your best bet.

```
(Get-SPSite "https://SITECOLLECTION/").RecycleBin | ?{$_.Web -match "Sub Site"}
```

or

```
(Get-SPSite "https://SITECOLLECTION/").RecycleBin | ?{($_.DeletedDate -gt "5/13/2019") -and ($_.DeletedDate -lt "5/15/2019")}
```

You should be able to filter by any of the following.

```
Web           
ID              
ItemState       
ItemType        
Title           
DirName         
LeafName        
Author         
AuthorId        
AuthorName      
AuthorEmail     
DeletedBy       
DeletedById     
DeletedByName   
DeletedByEmail  
DeletedDate     
Size            
ProgId          
ImageUrl
```